# I can't figure out how to add an text dynamically to the screen in a specific "X,Y" location

Tags: javascript, text

I need to add a text to the screen in a specific location. does anyone have any sample code they can post??
Example: lets say I had to add "This is a text" to 50px left and 100px top but I had to do it dynamically. how could I do it??

Thanks!

PS I'm **VERY** new to Javascript :]

Comment: You can start here: [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position). I suppose that page will give you some ideas, and you'll be able to post some code too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do that with JavaScript:

```
// Create an HTML paragraph to hold the text
var p = document.createElement('p');

// Add some text to it
p.innerHTML = "Some text <span>and markup</span>";

// Give it position: absolute so you can position by x,y
p.style.position = 'absolute';

// Define position
p.style.left = '50px';
p.style.top = '100px';

// Add it to the body
document.body.appendChild(p);
```